# What are these ACS containers under my subnet objects?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have ACS folders under my subnet objects in sites and services.

Did some googling and now I'm more confused.

Apparently this is Windows QoS Admission Control Service- which is Windows implementation of QoS? RSVP Messages, Flowspecs and Filterspecs, what is all this stuff I've never heard of this.

I haven't found any up to date docs on this so I assume it is an old product? This isn't an AD related thing is it?

Would this have been from some product that might have been installed in my domain a long time ago that created these objects in sites and services or is it a default AD thing?

Edit: I spoke too soon I have an ACS folder under only a few subnet objects (not all of the subnet objects have it):

[image]

I have an ACS folder under Services as well:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this?

Comment: I certainly will

Comment: I'd admit that I wasn't aware of this node until now (my environment doesn't have it). Did a bit googling and it seems something left over from windows 2000 days (you already know it's QoS related), and later versions don't honor it any more. Although I am pretty sure you can safely remove those, but the golden rule is "don't fix something that is not broken". Won't bother me anyway.